# How to find the space of Linux servers by iterating the text file which consist list of servers

Tags: linux, shell, powershell

I have a text file list of 100 servers, I want to login to each server and need to get the server space details.

I have a PowerShell command `$DiskReport = ForEach($Servernames in ($File))` but it does not support Shell script/Linux.

I know how to read the list of server details from the text file, but I need to login each server with provided ssh credentials.

Please let me know if any one knows the solution for shell/Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Finally my script was working.....

```
while read Servers  

do 

ssh $Servers "login" 

done < Servers.txt
```